# UWP RfComm - StreamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync throws exception

Tags: bluetooth, uwp, serial-port, listener, rfcomm

I am trying to create a UWP app that listens for Bluetooth serial port connections. When I set up the listener in the application (via a button click) I get an exception at the line:

```
await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync( 
      rfcommProvider.ServiceId.ToString(),
      SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);`
```

The exception message is: 
***System.ArgumentException:** 'The parameter is incorrect.
'protectionLevel': Only plain sockets are allowed for IP StreamSocketListeners.'*

Here is the code:

```
private async void btnBluetoothServerClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var rfcommProvider = 
   await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);

   var socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();

   socketListener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;

   await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync( 
      rfcommProvider.ServiceId.ToString(),
      SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

   rfcommProvider.StartAdvertising(socketListener);
}
```

When the `protectionLevel` parameter `SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication`, is changed to, `SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket`as the exception indicates, the new exception message is: ***System.Exception:** 'The specified class was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007277D)'*.

The application manifest file includes:

```
<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />    
   <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
     <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
     </Device>
   </DeviceCapability>
   <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <Device Id="any">        
         <Function Type="name:serialPort" />       
      </Device>
   </DeviceCapability>
   <DeviceCapability Name="wifiControl" /> 
</Capabilities>
```

It seems that this code should work according to the documentation at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocketListener_BindServiceNameAsync_System_String_Windows_Networking_Sockets_SocketProtectionLevel_Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkAdapter_

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change parameter of the [`BindServiceNameAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocketListener_BindServiceNameAsync_System_String_Windows_Networking_Sockets_SocketProtectionLevel_Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkAdapter_) method,

```
rfcommProvider.ServiceId.ToString()
```

to

```
rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString()
```

then your code snippet will work.

The `AsString()` method of [`RfcommServiceId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommserviceid) will convert the `RfcommServiceId` to a string.`ToString` will return the type which is not the correct parameter for `BindServiceNameAsync`.

More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat).

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I can't believe I missed that little detail that caused me an hour of thinking  I was losing my mind!